# Why DOjo Date Pickers ar not coming

Tags: dojo

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/dojo.xd.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad: true"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.require("dijit.form.DateTextBox");
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <label for="fromDate">Fromfd:</label>
    <input id="fromDate" type="text" name="fromDate" dojoType="dijit.form.DateTextBox" required="true" onChange="dijit.byId('toDate').constraints.min = arguments[0];"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As a general rule, if others are going to be reading your code it's common courtesy to put some effort into formatting it nicely.

Comment: For future reference, write a bit more text in your question about the problem. Writing a 7-word question in the title and dumping only code in the question body will lead to closed questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to properly close the script tag. Correct usage:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/dojo.xd.js"
    djConfig="parseOnLoad: true">
</script>
```

The script tag doesn't work when closed using normal XHTML empty tag style. Why? Check here:

[Why don't self-closing script tags work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)